# Best way to generate a sports schedule with restrictions, byes and rest days

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have created a schedule generator to match games to calendar dates with some restrictions, after some review it does not run in an usable time.

The schedule is for a 2 conference, 4 divisions, 6 teams league with two byes (not on the first 4 or last 4 weeks), teams that play in the same stadium cannot play at home in the same day.

It's a 24 week season, each team plays 10 division games(5 at home, 5 away), 6 games against a division in the conference (3 home, 3 away), 6 games against a division in another conference (3 home, 3 away) and 2 more games against the teams in your conference that had the same standing as you last year in the conference division you didn't play against.

When you play a different division if you play at home, next time you face that division you will play away and vice-versa.

My approach was to create all the games, handpick the restrictions first and then just randomly try to fit all the games until I get a working schedule. Also tried a depth first solution without success.

Are there any solutions out there that allow to calculate this schedule in at most 1 hour? Preference would be almost instantly, don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Assume your readers are algorithm experts, but have no knowledge of sports, what kinds of restrictions might apply in that context, or the measures my which we'd evaluate the quality of a schedule. Edit your question to ensure your problem is fully-specified with all the constraint rules that need to be honoured and all the qualities we should try to optimize for in a high-quality schedule.

Comment: Is that better @DMGregory ?

Comment: "Among" is not enough. We need a complete list. "Due to conferences and divisions" would be much clearer if you included a sample of these conferences and divisions, so we understand what sets of teams need to play against which other sets. If you can share a complete test case, folks can test their proposed answers against that case to verify that it correctly solves all the constraints, in a situation representative of the ones you need to solve. Every degree of freedom or ambiguity you leave is an opportunity for someone to make an assumption that makes their answer not work for your case.

Comment: Hope it's more unambiguous @DMGregory .

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you are doing can (but does not necessarily have to) be described as a scheduling problem from the field of optimization/operations research. You can define the scheduling task as an mathematical optimization problem and than use a solver (= a software for solving optimization problems) to get many feasible solutions.

Of course there might also be other ways of doing this. I can just tell you that for example the German Basketball League (BBL) and the National Football League in the US (NFL) are doing it like this. They use the commercial solver **Gurobi** for generating feasible schedules. Here you can read about these case studies:

- [BBL case study](https://www.gurobi.com/case_study/bbl-english/)
- [NFL case study](https://www.gurobi.com/lp/or/nfl-tackles-scheduling-problem-with-gurobi/)

Of course, you can also use free solvers (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optimization_software#Free_and_open-source_software)). The method you are using (some kind of a brute force approach) is quite inefficient for large-scale optimization problems.

Comment: What can I look into to define my scheduling tasks as a mathematical optimization problem? I also updated my question with more detail.

Comment: Hi MadCatPT. Basically defining optimization problems is something that you have to learn from scratch. This is often taugth in universities. Here is some further information about sport scheduling: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep521/07wi/prj/sam_scott.pdf

Comment: Maybe there are also freeware tools for this or some open code (e.g. at Github) for generating sports schedules. To be totally honest, I am not an expert on sports scheduling. I do have experience with optimization and algorithms and I knew that your problem is infact solved (on a large scale) by mathematical optimization techniques. This is I just wanted to make you aware of this option

Comment: Algorithmically speaking, you can of course try to design some heuristic algorithm (a better one than you basically did) and I assume that there are also some algorithmic techniques for that purpose. By the way: There is an Operations Research community at stack exchange (https://or.stackexchange.com/) that could help you with formulating the optimization problem and giving you further information.